# Hebrew text data from AS400 shown backwards When downloading data using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ibm-midrange

I have SSIS package that downloading data from table in AS400 server to table in MSSQL,
I'm using **IBM AS/400 Client Access Express** driver to access the as400, but data that contains Hebrew text just gets downloaded backwardly for example 'דוגמה' ----> 'המגוד'
I'm sure it's something wrong with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue before when I was working in Israel.
I'm not 100% sure anymore what i did to resolve this, but make sure the default codepage of the package is hebrew

Comment: For all this people who having this problem i wanna say, i found the solution is turn on bidirectional language support in IBM AS/400 Client Access Express