# IIS 7.5 writes reverse Hebrew to AS/400 while IIS Express does not

Tags: c#, iis, ibm-midrange, iis-express, db2-400

I have a web service written in C# 5.0 (.NET 4.5) that writes data into an AS/400 database using ODBC. Some of the fields are Hebrew strings. When running it using IIS Express, it works fine; but when using IIS 7.5 or 8.5, the Hebrew fields are written backward. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Is there a configuration that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

My comment to an answer composed by @Dror T may overlook an additional *layout transformation* that could occur, above and beyond simply having the effect of CCSID translation applied; i.e. a *bidirectional* feature requested of the client may be what is ¿*required*? additionally, just as implied.?  When I typed that comment, I was thinking that the *layout transformation* was something to be done at the client for presentation purposes, and this topic is about writing data into the database.

Unsure though, why that would not be a feature available on a connection string? Seems no mention anywhere in [IBM i 7.1->Connecting to your system->IBM i Access->IBM i Access for Windows->Programming->IBM i Access for Windows: Database programming->IBM i Access ODBC->Implementation issues of ODBC APIs->Connection string keywords](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/connectkeywords.htm) nor drilled-down specifically to the [Connection string keywords - **Conversion properties**](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordstranprop.htm), with regard to the alluded **bidirectional** feature setting/attribute.

Note: The OP refers to IBM i Client Access, so that is why those docs are referenced above; besides, I have not yet stored any links to newer IBM i Access Client Solutions (iACS) docs, nor did I quickly find a link to connection string details corresponding to those above. Although a quick look did find a possible high-level link for one of two *application packages* available for each of Windows and Linux [IBM i Access Client Solutions: Application Packages](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahg/rzahgicca2.htm)

Here I am adding a link to another topic, though that topic similarly does not explain specifically/explicitly [e.g. drill-down or connection-string or by some other configuration setting] how a user would "**turn on bidirectional language support**", as if somehow that would just be implicitly understood; that topic was instead, about reading data from the IBM i database files, rather than writing data, but similarly calls out *backward* text in BiDi language support:
[Hebrew text data from AS400 shown backwards When downloading data using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036038/hebrew-text-data-from-as400-shown-backwards-when-downloading-data-using-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The Client Access ODBC driver has a "bidirectional" feature that you can check in order to reverse right-to-left languages. This feature has a bug and works only for the user who checked it. There is a need to write a procedure that does this conversion.

Comment: Seems to me, that *feature* might just be an *override*, as applied to character data stored as *binary* vs properly-tagged with a BIDI CCSID; i.e. perhaps a sibling to the *override* of "force translation", which basically is a *trick* to be used only when the database TABLE columns are incorrectly tagged as CCSID(\*HEX)?  Indeed such an *override* would apply only to the user who has checked that option, because [and I would expect that] the **standard behavior** should be to translate the data between the client and the server, as a process for which the direction of the data is maintained.